# How can a FTP client pass data to the FTP server if FTP server denies the connection due to dynamic IP?

Tags: ftp, iot

There is an IoT device that runs a FTP client which periodically transfers the collected data to the FTP server. IoT device is provided with the internet but the IP of the device gets randomly assigned as it uses retail SIM card. Other hand, FTP has some strigent security rules because of this, it deines the client's connection if IP is changing.

Is there a solution to this problem without altering anything at the FTP server end?

Comment: perhaps use a proxy with a static IP?

Comment: This question cant be answered without a lot more information - including how the network is set up and how powerful the IOT device is.  A VPN might be the answer.

Comment: The best solution is not to use FTP, but instead sftp or scp if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Its a raspberry Pi powered IoT device that has 1 GB RAM and it uses a retail SIM card. FTP configuration is the basic non-encrypted mode. @davidgo What more information is required?

Comment: Regarding sftp/scp solution, Could you please add more information why you recommend these instead of FTP? @Bib

Comment: @Bib if SCP/SFTP is an option server side  it is a no-brainer over FTP.  It is (a) Much simpler to implement and (b) way more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, if you can use SCP or SFTP instead of FTP, definitely do that instead.   (I'd argue that an SCP/SFTP connection which uses public/private key encryption over a random IP is - on balance - more secure then a FTP connection locked down to an IP address)

If that is not an option, you can solve this problem with a VPN.    Ideally you would want to set up a VPN which is on the same network as the FTP server - this will give you the greatest speeds and will be the cheapest.   However if you can't do this for some reason, you could get a VPN **whose purpose is to provide a static IP** and route over that.   (Google "VPN Static IP" - there are lots of providers, but you probably won't find a free one).  The idea would then be to set up a VPN from the Pi to your VPN provider, route the traffic destined to the FTP server across the VPN and to the FTP server, where it will be seen as coming from the static IP address.

A Pi is capable of running both OpenVPN and Wireguard.  Wireguard is likely a better solution as its often simpler to set up and much lighter weight.